# How to download all subdirectories with wget?

Tags: download, wget, subdirectory

I'm using wget with these parameters but I doesn't download the files in the subdirectories:

```
wget -r --no-parent --user=user --password=pass http://www.domain.com/download
```

The -r argument is for recursive but I only get the files of the download/ directory. Do I need some other arguments?

Answer (score 0):

You should set the maximum [depth](http://www.gnu.org/software/wget/manual/html_node/Recursive-Retrieval-Options.html).